# pulsar-client couldn't be installed

Tags: python, apache-pulsar, python-pulsar

I cannot install `pulsar-client` as it is mentioned in the documentation at all:

```
pip3 install pulsar-client
```

> Collecting pulsar-client ERROR: Could not find a version that
>   satisfies the requirement pulsar-client (from versions: none) ERROR:
>   No matching distribution found for pulsar-client

```
pip3 install pulsar-client==2.4.0
```

> Collecting pulsar-client==2.4.0 ERROR: Could not find a version that
>   satisfies the requirement pulsar-client==2.4.0 (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for pulsar-client==2.4.0

I am on Windows 10, `python 3` version.

tried both `python` 2 and 3 versions.

Answer (score 4):

Just to be clear everybody, this is not supported in Windows 10 anymore. Can be used Linux, MacoS or others.

Answer (score 1):

After looking all over, i found out that for MacOS, pulsar-client only supports macOS (>= 11.0) with python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10 and Linux (including Alpine Linux) with python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10

To install a specific python:

```
run: brew install python@3.10
run: which python3.10

/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.10
```

Create a virtual env with that python version

```
virtualenv -p /opt/homebrew/bin/python3.10 myenv

source myenv/bin/activate

pip install pulsar-client
```

This worked with no issues on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to build the C++ client if you are on an unusual platform.  More platforms have support for the pre-built Python.

We are on 2.10.0 now and the client works in more environments.

If you can't use the Python client, you can try Go, Java, C#, or others.

Pulsar clusters can also accept MQTT, Kafka, Websockets, and other protocols if you need to.

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/client-libraries/

https://github.com/tspannhw/SpeakerProfile